# React component being called before fetch is complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the below function in React but I have the problem where the fetch isn't completing in time to pass data to the Chart component. So the chart renders with no graph.

```
export const OverviewChart = () => {
  type dateValue = {
    x: number,
    y: number
  }

  var data: Array<dateValue> = Array();

  const fetchFromUrl = async() =>{
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/tempData/monthly.csv`)
    const responseText = await response.text();
    const parsedResponse = readString(responseText);

    parsedResponse.data.forEach(x => {
        data.push( {x: Number(new Date(x[0])), y: Number(x[1]) } )
    })
  }

  fetchFromUrl();
  
  return(
    <Chart data={data} currentValue={1840.87}/>
  );
}
```

I have a redraw function on my graph so when I resize, it renders properly but I would like it to render properly without having to resize it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to be using state properly:

```
export const OverviewChart = () => {
  type dateValue = {
    x: number,
    y: number
  }

const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
  let results = [];
  const fetchFromUrl = async() =>{
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/tempData/monthly.csv`)
    const responseText = await response.text();
    const parsedResponse = readString(responseText);

    parsedResponse.data.forEach(x => {
        results.push( {x: Number(new Date(x[0])), y: Number(x[1]) } )
    })
    setData(results);
  }

  fetchFromUrl();
}, []);
  return(
    <Chart data={data} currentValue={1840.87}/>
  );
}
```

It should re-render automatically doing it this way, if not that I would just not render the chart until you have data:

```
  return data.length ? (
    <Chart data={data} currentValue={1840.87}/>
  ) : 'Loading...';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a Loading verification on your component return.
Here is a simple-sample:

```
import React from 'react'

export const ComponentName = () => {

  //React Hooks
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true)

  const fetchFromUrl = async() =>{
    const response = await fetch(`your fetch`)
    //other operations

    //when job operations done loading is defined as false
    setIsLoading(false)
    }

  fetchFromUrl();
  
  return(
    !isLoading? // = !(isLoading === true) => false; when isloading false, return false 
      <Component data={"data"} otherProps="props"/>
      : null //OR (not recommended)
    //<LoadingComponent /> // (recomended) OR
    //<SpinningLoadingComponent /> // (recommended)
    // is recommended to see loading when user call this component
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i think once I move this component over onto the main environment I'll make use of something like what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put data onto state. For that, you need to rewrite the stateless component to inherit React.Component. Another way is to call forceUpdate, which is not recommended.
2. Until the data are fetched, you need to render an empty component or loading spinner. Once the fetch is successful, you need to call setState and that will call render method again and draw charts correct.